# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

On my local WAMP stack things are working perfectly.

When I upload the database on GOdaddy.com, this error shows up.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What does it mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174183/warning-mysqli-connect-hy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernameloca

Comment: @user69104, if you get an error message that contains using password: NO, it means that you tried to log in without a password.  for ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhani find the solution. solution is change the host name . my localhost is 50.62.300.6 and i use there localshost. thats why show error .

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the root account on your local machine doesn't have a password.
That's why you can login locally with `using password: NO`

Probably your server on godaddy has a password set, or the root account disabled. You need to fix the credentials in your application (and probably use a login other than `root`)

Comment: tom i find the solution . solution is simple just change my localhost ..local host is mine 50.62.300.9 . i change to this one and script working.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP seems to handle the root username differently than WAMP.  I had to include the root password as 'root' in my PHP script, instead of leaving it blank, as such:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
```